# How do you use fetch api to an ec2 instance?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to find a good free server for our school project so I've decided to try ec2 and just make my pc the server that I will use. I've managed to install my node server onto the ec2. I can post requests using postman but when I'm trying to fetch data from my html file to the ec2 instance, it says:

`Fetch API cannot load ec2xxxxxx.amazonaws.com:3000/login. URL scheme "ecxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com" is not supported.`

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: " fetch data from my html file to the ec2 instance" - what does it mean? fetch how? How exactly are you testing your api?

Comment: Fetch as in fetch api. I'm sending post requests containing login data to the ec2 instance

Comment: Are you referring to [Fetch API - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure your application is listening on port 3000: netstat -anp |
   grep 3000 also telnet 127.0.0.1 3000
2. Then make sure that local firewall is configured to allow incoming access to port 3000 OR  disable local firewall to do a quick test (service iptables stop). for linux, its usually iptables
3. Allow incoming access to port 3000 in your AWS security group.

Answer (score 0):

The error is literally telling you what the problem is:

> "URL scheme... is not supported"

Do you know what the ["scheme" portion of a url is](https://www.w3.org/TR/app-uri/)? This link should help, but it's the something:// portion of a uri/url.

So it indicates that you need to specify a scheme that will get you to your aws server, which is likely either http:// or https://

So to be clear your fetch needs `fetch('http://ec2xxxxxx.amazonaws.com:3000/login').`